# gsutil installation error "egg_info" failed in /tmp/pip-build/boto

Tags: python, pip, gsutil

I have a problem when i try to install gsutil via pip on OpenSuse:

```
$ pip install gsutil
```

I've installed all dependencies like python-devel, openssl, openssl-devel etc to install gsutil, but it still could not be solved.

Any suggestion?

The Error:

```
             Downloading/unpacking gsutil
    Running setup.py egg_info for package gsutil

      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'gslib/commands/update.py'
      warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'scripts'
  Downloading/unpacking boto==2.38.0 (from gsutil)
    Running setup.py egg_info for package boto
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/setup.py", line 37, in <module>
          from boto import __version__
        File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
          from boto.storage_uri import BucketStorageUri, FileStorageUri
        File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/storage_uri.py", line 27, in <module>
          from boto.s3.deletemarker import DeleteMarker
        File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/s3/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
          from boto.regioninfo import RegionInfo, get_regions
        File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/regioninfo.py", line 27, in <module>
          from boto.exception import BotoClientError
        File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/exception.py", line 28, in <module>
          import xml.sax
      ImportError: No module named xml.sax
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

    File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/setup.py", line 37, in <module>

      from boto import __version__

    File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>

      from boto.storage_uri import BucketStorageUri, FileStorageUri

    File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/storage_uri.py", line 27, in <module>

      from boto.s3.deletemarker import DeleteMarker

    File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/s3/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>

      from boto.regioninfo import RegionInfo, get_regions

    File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/regioninfo.py", line 27, in <module>

      from boto.exception import BotoClientError

    File "/tmp/pip-build/boto/boto/exception.py", line 28, in <module>

      import xml.sax

  ImportError: No module named xml.sax

  ----------------------------------------
  Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/boto
  Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Recently, I've just tried to install it via google cloud sdk as https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#linux. but it gives a python error like ImportError: No module named xml.sax

Comment: i solved it. I re-installed python-xml and this problem solved.